# Android SQLite - force increase on integer column

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table which store data on fuel used by a particular vehicle. One of the column is current_mileage. Is there any way I can constrain this table to only accept increasing values for this column? I.e. if row 1 has 1000 as the current_mileage, then row 2's  current_mileage must be 1001 or above.

Many thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) to enforce this constraint.

Here's an example that assumes your table is named `FuelConsumption`, and contains a `vehicle_id` column (just guessing, you'll want to store more than one vehicle's fuel consumption? -- if not, just leave out the WHERE clause in the WHEN part):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_bi_FuelConsumption
BEFORE INSERT ON FuelConsumption
WHEN NEW.current_mileage <= (SELECT MAX(current_mileage) FROM FuelConsumption WHERE vehicle_id = NEW.vehicle_id)
BEGIN
    RAISE(ABORT, 'Fuel consumption cannot decrease');
END;
```

I would also advise putting a UNIQUE constraint on the combination of (`vehicle_id, current_mileage`).  This will make sure that an index is created (thereby quite speeding up the WHEN portion of the trigger), and will catch identical values even before the trigger.

If you don't want to add a UNIQUE constraint, then at least add a (non-unique) index to your table, on those two columns.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you tell me, will an insert, which will execute this trigger, be an atomic operation or do I need to do the insert within an Android transaction.

Comment: AFAIK, a trigger in SQLite is always atomic by default.  But this trigger doesn't actually _do_ anything; it just raises an error if a certain condition is met (new mileage not higher than current).  The '[ABORT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)' keyword after RAISE determines the conflict handler used. Check the link for the other options.

Comment: @barry: if my answer was useful, could you upvote it?  And if it answered your question, could you "accept" it? (click the green checkmark to the left of the answer)  It’ll earn you points (allowing you to upvote, for instance), and me as well.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `current_mileage` your primary key?

Comment: It may well be some sort of key, but that won't force it to increase for each new row. Barry

Comment: yes - having it as a primary key with `identity` will allow it to keep incrementing.

Comment: Ok, but it needs to accept a user's input, not autoincrement by 1 for each row. Barry

Answer (score 0):

You cannot constrain that in the table creation. You will have to do it by your self programaticall, and, before inserting new data. So you can have something like:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT current_mileage FROM table_name ORDER BY current_mileage DESC LIMIT 1");
c.moveToFirst();
int max = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("current_mileage"));
```

Then, you have to make sure that the next insert must contain a `current_mileage` that is greater than `max`.

Comment: Thanks - I'm happy to do that, just wanted to know if the was a SQL way to do it. Barry

Answer (score -1):

Databases do not inherently know anything about order of the rows they store; it is not part of the theory around databases.  This kind of logic is better served by business rules in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wanted to know if the was a SQL way to do it as I'd rather let the database do the database work where possible. Barry

Comment: -1: he's not asking about the order of the rows, he's asking about the _values_ contained in them.  There's a huge difference.

Comment: He's got an implied order to the rows that he wants to enforce -- that no row for a given vehicle ever has a mileage lower than any other row in the set.  This implies rows older than the current row.